# $X,Y \sim U[0,1]$, what is the probability that $t^2+Xt+Y=0 $ has a real root.

Tags: probability, random-variables, roots, uniform-distribution

Let the continuous random variables $X,Y$ be independent of each other and uniformly distributed on $[0,1] $ i.e. $X,Y \sim U[0,1]$, what is the probability that $t^2+Xt+Y=0 $ has a real root?

I am trying to solve it with Geometric probability models, knowing $X^2-4Y \ge 0$. But I think the real answer should be related with r.v. and the properties of uniform distribution. What is the right way to solve the problem?

Anybody could help?

Many Thanks.

Comment: As you said, it's $\mathbb P\{X^2+4Y>0\}$.

Comment: @Surb But how can we calculate that, i.e. $ P$ {$ X^2+4Y>0$ }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the probability to have a real root is $P(X^2-4Y\geq 0)$

you can calculate it integrating

$$\int \int_{x^2\geq 4y} f(x,y)dxdy$$

being $f(x,y)=1$ the double integral is equivalent to the integration area

$$P(X^2\geq 4Y)=\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{4}dx=\frac{1}{12}$$